# Google Area Charts - Select all data sets for date - Combined Tooltip

Tags: charts, google-visualization, line

I'm trying to replicate the behaviour of Google Analytics Charts in my own app using the Google Charts Api.

In Google Analytics whenever i'm hovering over a date both data sets are selecting and i get a combined tooltip of both values for that date.

Can't find anything in the docs here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart ... and nothing on Google also.

LE: as i figured out the GA charts are Area Charts and not line charts:
Checked: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart but still can't find a way to mimic the behavior of GA charts ...

[image: selecting all points in current date]

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for this, the answer is the focusTarget property:
focusTarget: 'category'